# AngularJS using path to templateHtml as module name

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

i noticed that AngularJS UI Bootstrap uses the following approach for templates:

```
angular.module("uib/template/progressbar/bar.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("uib/template/progressbar/bar.html" }
```

So i think it's quite nice solution but what is the reason to create module for each template url like `angular.module("uib/template/progressbar/bar.html"` or `angular.module("uib/template/progressbar/progress.html"` etc

What benefits it will give to us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a module for each template separately will result in proper separation of code. Each module will Handel the code for each template and will prevent the user from mixing the code. It's quite a universal rule that a function or entity should do only its own duty and not more that that.